# Using DataStructures in FunctionCompile

Tags: compile, data-structures, data-types, function-compile

[This is a follow up to this StackExchange question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216665/how-to-use-datastructure-in-functioncompile)

I am trying to do the equivalent of Select on a "FixedArray" data structure.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
fixedArrayDS = CreateDataStructure["FixedArray", 2^10];
vanillaArray = RandomReal[{0, 1}, fixedArrayDS["Length"]];
Do[fixedArrayDS["SetPart", i, vanillaArray[[i]]], {i, Length[vanillaArray]}]
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Select[vanillaArray, # < 0.5 &]
```

without extracting all the elements (i.e, this:
Select[fixedArrayDS["Elements"], # < 0.5 &]
is considered "cheating")

Let's try to compile a function to do this (I am trying to teach myself how to use FunctionCompile with data structures).  Sow and Reap seems a plausible way to do this.

```
select = FunctionCompile[
  Function[
   {Typed[fa, "FixedArray"], Typed[bound, "Real64"]},
   Last[
    Reap[
     Do[
      If[fa["Part", i] < bound, Sow[fa["Part", i]]],
      {i, 1, fa["Length"]}
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

doesn't work and comes back with a TypeError stating that a version of Reap can't be found that takes one argument.  I'll come back to why Reap isn't going to work later and a hypothesis about using KernelFunction later.

As sanity checks. Test and see if this is the correct syntax for FunctionCompile on this data structure.

```
first = FunctionCompile[
  Function[
   {Typed[fa, "FixedArray"], Typed[multiplier, "Real64"]},
   fa["Part", 1] multiplier
   ]
  ]
```

this works

```
first[fixedArrayDS, 1]
```

so the FunctionCompile syntax seems to be correct.

Another sanity check. See if Compile works with Reap and Sow:

```
cf = Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real}},
  Last[Reap[
    Do[
     If[l[[i]] < b, Sow[l[[i]]]],
     {i, 1, Length[l]}
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

which works, but is slower than the built-in Select:

```
RepeatedTiming[cf[vanillaArray, .5]]
```

Back to the original problem. Getting clues from [Tom Wickham Jones' talk in 2020](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=2907). Reap is not going to work because it isn't in the following list:

```
Needs["Compile`Utilities`Support`"]
Compile`Utilities`SupportedSymbols[]
```

Perhaps using KernelFunction in the FunctionCompile would work--but how would I use Type for Reap?

Another solution might be to use another data structure that has a rapid Append:

```
select = FunctionCompile[
  Function[
   {Typed[fa, "FixedArray"], Typed[bound, "Real64"]},
   Block[{collection = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"]},
    Do[
     If[fa["Part", i] < bound, collection["Append", fa["Part", i]]],
     {i, 1, fa["Length"]}
     ];
    collection
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

But, this doesn't compile either.

Finally, there is a hint that there is a solution for this task that might be in development.  See around minute 51:30 in the [TWJ talk linked above](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=2907); it appears there is a package for using Iterators that would be a natural implement select.

```
Needs["IteratorTools`"]
```

But it looks like it didn't ship with 12.3.

Comment: I have an unsatisfactory solution: RepeatedTiming[Reap@fixedArrayDS["Fold", If[#2 < 0.5, Sow[#2]] &, 1]].  This is about 15 times slower than the builtin Select[vanillaList, #<0.5 &] and 2 times slower than Select[fixedArrayDS["Elements"], # < .5 &]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I give a simplified version below that is slightly faster than the solution from illan.

```
select=FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[pa,"PackedArray"["Real64",1]],Typed[bound,"Real64"]},
Module[{da,elem},
  da=CreateDataStructure@"DynamicArray";
  Do[
    elem=Part[pa,i];
    If[elem<bound,da["Append",elem]],{i,1,Length@pa}
  ];
  Developer`ToPackedArray@da]
]];
```

Then we use it like so

```
array = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
select[array, 0.5];
```

**Update**

However, I find the implementation below that uses Compile is almost twice as fast and the implementation above. Considering that and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291161/compile-vs-functioncompile/291180#291180) example, it seems using Compile can usually give a faster program than using FunctionCompile.

```
selectCompiled=Compile[{{array,_Real,1},{bound,_Real}},Module[{elem,bag=Internal`Bag[]},
Do[
  elem=Compile`GetElement[array,n];
  If[elem<bound,Internal`StuffBag[bag,elem]],{n,Length@array}
];
Internal`BagPart[bag,All]],RuntimeOptions->"Speed",CompilationTarget->"C"];
```

Comment: Nice and efficient.

Answer (score 14):

This is a bit too long for a comment, but below is a slightly modified version that uses the `"DynamicArray"` approach.

The basic issue is that all the precompiled versions of data structures that can be used in top-level WL via `CreateDataStructure` are only available for the `"Expression"` type.

The underlying implementations are actually polymorphic and can be instantiated for different types, but only in compiled code.

However, the results (e.g. a `"FixedArray"` or a `"DynamicArray"` with `"Real64"` elements) cannot be used directly in top-level, although they can be passed in to compiled code. This is why the result of `select` is converted prior to returning it.

```
select = 
  FunctionCompile[
   Function[{Typed[fa, "FixedArray"["Real64"]], 
     Typed[bound, "Real64"]}, 
    Block[{collection = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"]}, 
     Do[If[fa["Part", i] < bound, 
       collection["Append", fa["Part", i]]], {i, 1, fa["Length"]}];
     Developer`ToPackedArray[collection]]]];

toFixedArrayReal64 = 
  FunctionCompile[
   Function[{Typed[pa, "PackedArray"["Real64", 1]]},
    Module[{len, res},
     len = Length[pa];
     res = CreateDataStructure["FixedArray", 0., len];
     Do[res[[i]] = pa[[i]], {i, len}];
     res]]];

len = 2^20;
vanillaArray = RandomReal[{0, 1}, len];
fixedArray = toFixedArrayReal64[vanillaArray];

RepeatedTiming[res1 = Select[vanillaArray, # < 0.5 &];]

(* {0.395801, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[res2 = select[fixedArray, 0.5];]

(* {0.0183779, Null} *)

res1 === res2

(* True *)
```

Comment: This is very instructive! The speed-up is very impressive.  Accepting you “long comment” as an answer.   @ilian, if you are inclined and have the time to say a few words the expected use cases for this new functionality, I think others besides me will benefit.   I imagine that tutorials are on their way.