# Compile vs FunctionCompile

Tags: compile, function-comparison, function-compile

I wanted to look at the pros & cons of Compile & FunctionCompile. This code below is from Neat Examples in [FunctionCompile](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompile.html?q=FunctionCompile) documentation.

```
restrictFlow[ x_, y_]:=Module[{z},
  z=1-1/(x+I y)^2;
  {{x,y},{Re[z],-Im[z]}}
];

decl=FunctionDeclaration[restrictFlow, Typed[{"Real64","Real64"}->"PackedArray"::["Real64",2]]@DownValuesFunction[restrictFlow]];

func=Function[{Typed[x0,"Real64"],Typed[x1,"Real64"],Typed[y0,"Real64"], Typed[y1,"Real64"]},
  Table[Flatten[ Table[{restrictFlow[x+d/4,y], restrictFlow[x+d/4,-y]},{x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1}],2] ,{d, 0,3, 0.05}]
];

usingFunctionCompile=FunctionCompile[decl, func];
```

Next I try to do the same thing using Compile.

```
usingCompiled=Compile[{{x0,_Real},{x1,_Real},{y0,_Real},{y1,_Real}},
  Module[{zP,zM},
    Table[Flatten[ Table[
      zP=1-1/(x+d/4+I y)^2;
      zM=1-1/(x+d/4-I y)^2;
      {{{x,y},{Re[zP],-Im[zP]}}, {{x,-y},{Re[zM],-Im[zM]}}},
      {x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1}],2] ,{d, 0,3, 0.05}
    ]
 ]];
```

I find that the above implementations return nearly the same results. Any ideas how we can make them return exactly the same results? Now look at the timing comparison.

```
RepeatedTiming[compileResult = usingCompiled[-7,5,0.5, 3];]
(*  {0.00125593, Null} *)
```

and

```
RepeatedTiming[functionCompileResult = usingFunctionCompile[-7,5,0.5, 3];]
(* {0.00273739, Null} *)
```

The CompiledCodeFunction that takes over twice as long to evaluate than the version written with Compile. Coding with Compile is much easier than coding with FunctionCompile. Compile[] evaluates almost instantly, but FunctionCompile[] takes a while to compile. Am I right that we should only use FunctionCompile when we can't use Compile?

Answer (score 21):

On my M1 Max processor and with *Mathematica* 13.2.1.0, the speed differences are even more severe:

```
RepeatedTiming[
 functionCompileResult = usingFunctionCompile[-7, 5, 0.5, 3];
 ]

RepeatedTiming[
 compileResult = usingCompiled[-7, 5, 0.5, 3];
 ]
```

> {0.00305243, Null}
>
> {0.000576201, Null}

By using `CompilationTarget -> "C"` and by performing some simplifications on compile time, I can squeeze out even some more performance from `Compile`:

```
usingCompiled2 = Block[{zP, zM, x, y, d},
   
   zP = 1 - 1/(x + d + I y)^2;
   zM = 1 - 1/(x + d - I y)^2;
   
   With[{code = 
      N@ComplexExpand[{{{x, y}, {Re[zP], -Im[zP]}}, {{x, -y}, {Re[zM], -Im[zM]}}}]},
    
    Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {x1, _Real}, {y0, _Real}, {y1, _Real}},
     Table[code, {d, 0., 0.25 3., 0.25 0.05}, {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}]
     , CompilationTarget -> "C"
     ]
    
    ]
   ];
```

Here the timing:

```
RepeatedTiming[  compileResult2 = usingCompiled2[-7, 5, 0.5, 3];  ]
```

> {0.0000944208, Null}

And by leaving out `Flatten` and by doing the rearrangement with `ArrayFlatten` outside the compiled function, I get even a tiny bit more:

```
usingCompiled3 = Block[{zP, zM, x, y, d},
   
   zP = 1 - 1/(x + d + I y)^2;
   zM = 1 - 1/(x + d - I y)^2;
   
   With[{code = N@ComplexExpand[{{{x, y}, {Re[zP], -Im[zP]}}, {{x, -y}, {Re[zM], -Im[zM]}}}]},
    
    Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {x1, _Real}, {y0, _Real}, {y1, _Real}},
     Table[code, {d, 0., 0.25 3., 0.25 0.05}, {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}]
     , CompilationTarget -> "C"
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

And here the experiment:

```
RepeatedTiming[
 compileResult3 = usingCompiled3[-7, 5, 0.5, 3];
 dim = Dimensions[compileResult3];
 compileResult3 = ArrayReshape[compileResult3, {dim[[1]], dim[[2]] dim[[3]] 2, 2, 2}];
 ]
```

> {0.0000802671, Null}

This is 38 times faster than `FunctionCompile`. And it needs only 0.45 seconds to compile, while `FunctionCompile` needs 20 seconds.

So, if `Compile` solves your problem, is easier to code with, compiles faster, and produces this much faster code, then it is really hard to make the case for `FunctionCompile`...

*To be fair, we have to note that `FunctionCompile` is marked as experimental. So it is still in development. And it can also do a couple of things that `Compile` cannot.*

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment, `FunctionCompile` is basically unusable, since it is so unreliable and unpredictable. This "experimental" feature is not ready for any sort of a release. There are fundamental implementation problems, and `FunctionCompile` can easily take a couple hours to "compile" (and fail sometimes) code that I can manually convert to vectorized assembly by hand faster than that, and I *suck at it* (have to look up all the opcodes, try things, etc.). At a point where doing it by hand is more reliable and faster, there's no reason for `FunctionCompile` to even be mentioned :(

Comment: Now, the promise of `FunctionCompile` is great - portable LLVM IR is a good thing, functions that can be compiled and easily reused, wow great. The user-facing functionality has great design. The implementation seems to be a flaming waste dump. I'm a bit sour since it has wasted me a lot of time, and after a bit digging into the sources via `PrintDefinitions` and fixing bugs in code we ostensibly pay good money for proved to be too aggravating :/